# Await using on enumerable

Tags: c#, async-await, using

I have a block of code where I want to apply the `using` statement to each command in the `commands` enumerable. What is the C# syntax for this?

```cs
await using var transaction = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync(cancel);
IEnumerable<DbCommand> commands = BuildSnowflakeCommands(conn, tenantId);

var commandTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var command in commands)
{
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    commandTasks.Add(command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel));
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(commandTasks);
}
catch (SnowflakeDbException)
{
    await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancel);
    return;
}

await transaction.CommitAsync(cancel);
```

Edit: Rider / ReSharper seems to think these two are equivalent, or at least I get a prompt to convert the `for` into a `foreach` (this is clearly **wrong**):

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < commands.Count; i++)
{
    await using var command = commands[i];
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    commandTasks.Add(command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel));
}
```

and

```cs
foreach (var command in commands)
{
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    commandTasks.Add(command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel));
}
```

Edit 2: After some discussion and a few helpful answers, this is what I'm going with:

```cs
var transaction = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync(cancel);
var commands = BuildSnowflakeCommands(conn, tenantId);

var commandTasks = commands.Select(async command =>
{
    await using (command)
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel);
    }
});

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(commandTasks);
    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancel);
}
catch (SnowflakeDbException)
{
    await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancel);
}
finally
{
    await transaction.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var commandTasks = commands.Select(async command =>
{
    using (command)
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel);
    }
});
```

The command will then be disposed as soon as it exits scope.

Full code:

```
await using var transaction = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync(cancel);
IEnumerable<DbCommand> commands = BuildSnowflakeCommands(conn, tenantId);

var commandTasks = commands.Select(async command =>
{
    using (command)
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel);
    }
});

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(commandTasks);
}
catch (SnowflakeDbException)
{
    await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancel);
    return;
}

await transaction.CommitAsync(cancel);
```

Definitely don't use the `for` loop example; the `await` will cause each command to happen in serial, as the completion of each query must be awaited before the next is initiated.

Comment: Doesn't this change the overall flow, though? As you're now awaiting inside the select?

Comment: @xandermonkey No, the `async` lambda will return a `Task` as soon as `await` is hit, allowing each command to happen in parallel. Each command will only be disposed once `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` is complete.

Comment: Ok. Another problem with this, though. The captured variable `transaction` is now disposed in the outer scope

Comment: @xandermonkey Are you still using `Task.WhenAll`? Disposing a `DbCommand` shouldn't dispose the `DbTransaction`.

Comment: Yes, I am using `Task.WhenAll`. If I swap out the loop for your select, the `transaction` is disposed in the outer scope

Comment: @xandermonkey That should not happen; multiple `DbCommand`s can be created and disposed within a single `DbTransaction`, and your `DbTransaction` does not leave scope until all commands have completed. Is your full code the same as my edit?

Comment: Apologies for the imgur link, easy way to show the warning hovertext: https://imgur.com/a/rHaTJTc

Comment: @xandermonkey, just use scoped transaction, In this case it will be safer and more readable

Comment: @xandermonkey Have you tried to run the code? Whilst the transaction is disposed in the outer scope, it won't leave scope until all the commands have completed.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay quite right, it does work. I'm editing my answer to show the full solution - I'm just going to dispose of the transaction manually to be safe.

Comment: @xandermonkey this is the best answer IMHO. It guarantees that the commands will be eventually disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync` a set of `IDisposable`s or `IAsyncDisposable`s using the language syntax alone.

You can iterate each one and call the appropriate method.  I would cache all the commands as an array or readonly collection before re-enumerating.

I would avoid disposing in your loop as your JetBrains tooling recommends. The command has to live longer than just that.

Personally, I would do something like this:

```
var commands = BuildSnowflakeCommands(conn, tenantId).ToArray();
var commandTasks = new List<Task>(commands.Length);

foreach (var command in commands)
{
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    commandTasks.Add(command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel));
}

/// later...
foreach (var command in commands)
{
    command.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Please see my edited post, I'm curious to look into this further.

Comment: `command.Dispose();` this is error-prone, the object might have been already disposed. `command?.Dispose();` is a bit more robust.

Comment: @PeterCsala the null propagation operator doesn't have to do with disposable at all.

Comment: Based on the implementation the `command` could point to `null` after an exception or after the dispose. So rather than exposing your program to throw `NullReferenceException` you can call the Dispose only if the command is not null.

Comment: @PeterCsala how - theres no null assignment to anything.... this is merely an example and the further tuning is up to the OP to figure out what to actually do.

Comment: Because we can see only an excerpt of the codebase we can't be sure that no one has called the Dispose on the that object (perhaps through a different pointer). But if you think that is an unnecessary safe guard then leave it as it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay sure. But that’s not in the post

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, that is true.